# Loaded ComboStore getting Destroy after passing from triggerCallbacks

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using a combobox with filtering the store data sometime. When I am editing the combo the filter store data getting destroyed. On further investigation I got that store is disappearing from this library function

```
triggerCallbacks: function() {
        debugger;
        var me = this,
            callback = me.getInternalCallback();

        if (callback) {
            callback.call(me.getInternalScope() || me, me); /// In This Line Store getting destroy.
            me.setInternalCallback(null);
            me.setInternalScope(null);
        }

        if (callback = me.getCallback()) {

            callback.call(me.getScope() || me, me.getRecords(), me, me.wasSuccessful());
            me.setCallback(null);
            me.setScope(null);
        }
    },
```

Any solution by which I can avoid this.